# Conditional probability of scoring more than $8$ questions correctly given at least $6$ is correct.

Tags: probability

> Question: In a multiple choice test, there are 20 questions, and each question has four choices. Jane is clueless and answers by purely guessing. She is equally likely to pick any of the possible choices, and each such choice is independent of the other ones. If it is known that Jane guessed correctly strictly more than six questions correctly, what is the chance that she scored strictly more than eight questions correctly?

I have attempted it and my work is shown below for this practice problem. However, I got it wrong and I am not sure why is the answer correct. Could anyone please tell me what I did wrong and how should I solve it?

My answer:

$$P(X > 8| X> 6) = \frac{P(X > 8)}{P(X>6)}=\frac{\sum_{i=9}^{20}\binom{20}{i}(0.75)^{20-i}(0.25)^i}{\sum_{i=7}^{20}\binom{20}{i}(0.75)^{20-i}(0.25)^i}$$

But answer provided was:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=7}^{20}\binom{20}{i}3^{20-i}}{\sum_{i=9}^{20}\binom{20}{i}3^{20-i}}$$

Comment: Please write an *informative* title.

Answer (score 2):

The "actual answer" can't be correct, since the numerator is greater than the denominator.

Probability can't exceed $1$.

Comment: If it is not correct, then what would the answer be?

Comment: your answer seems fine. please edit it using mathjax and use more informative title.

Comment: btw, spend some time going through [mathjax references](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) .For a start, try to surround mathy object with dollar signs. it doesn't have to be perfect for a start but you will receive more positive responses if you do so. Click on edit and read the mathjax syntaxes and learn from it. Also, try to get rid of common factors of the numerators and the denominator.